# list.files on R with a pattern from a list

Tags: r

So, I have this folder with more than 200 files. Each file is named as orto_[name]_bom.shp

[name] is the variable

I want to list only the 7 files (on the folder) that is on the vector below

```
name=c('ananindeua','belém','benevides','castanhal','marituba','santa bárbara do pará','santa izabel do pará')
```

My code is

```
files <- list.files(path = './data/regions/sector/',
                  pattern = paste0("orto_", name, "_bom.shp", full.names = TRUE)
```

But it is not returning all the seven files. It only returns the [ananindeua] one.

I wonder how code it.

Comment: at core, you've passed a vector to `pattern` but it only accepts length-1. so you've got to build the pattern into a single regex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try :

```
files <- list.files(path = './data/regions/sector/', 
          pattern = paste0("orto_", name, "_bom.shp", collapse = "|"), 
          full.names = TRUE)
```

Comment: slightly more efficient version: `orto_(?:ananideua|...|pará)_bom.shp`

Comment: @MichaelChirico, can you explain me the `?:` part?

Comment: @ricoderks this means "don't capture the group". usually, contents of () can be referred later with \1 \2 etc. however if you don't need to refer, it's inefficient to keep track

Comment: thanks, Ronak, it was really helpful. My list has some names with special characters as é á ã, etc. and it didn`t list the files that have it. But I managed the files with file.move and done my task.